# Accurate log PHP script processing times including image uploads

Tags: php, apache

How can I accurate log the time it takes for a script to process in PHP including the upload time of an image?

I've tried using

```
microtime()
```

but to no avail - it looks as if it's giving me the time it took for the script to actually process, but didn't include the 30 something minutes it took to upload a 1GB file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - this is for a test I need to run on some school work.

Disclaimer: It has nothing to do with my grade so I am not asking for homework help, I just would like to run some tests on my code.

Comment: The file upload is not really being done by PHP that will be down to your web server

Comment: Understood - is there a way to time that at all?